# Can you help to modify the query or other query for getting the expected result

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried many way but didn't get expected result. How can I get expected result.

You can download the [dbtable structure](http://52.77.142.126/orders.sql) from here :-

```
SELECT 
    IF(o.source_id = 1, 'online',0)  TYPE,
        MONTH(date_created) AS monthvalue
        ,SUM(total_price) AS totalSale
FROM orders o
WHERE   o.source_id = 1  AND  date_created BETWEEN(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY monthvalue

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    IF(o.source_id = 2, 'visit',0)  TYPE,
        MONTH(date_created) AS monthvalue
        ,SUM(total_price) AS totalSale
FROM orders o
WHERE   o.source_id =2 AND  date_created BETWEEN(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY monthvalue

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    IF(o.source_id = 3, 'phone',0)  TYPE,
        MONTH(date_created) AS monthvalue
        ,SUM(total_price) AS totalSale
FROM orders o
WHERE   o.source_id = 3 AND  date_created BETWEEN(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY monthvalue
```

Got Result :-

```
TYPE    monthvalue  totalSale   
online  6            38300
visit   6            16800
phone   5              500
phone   6             7150
```

Expected Result :

```
Type    May     June
online  0       38300
Visit   0       16800
Phone   500      7150
```

Comment: Seems, you want to count `source_id` for each month. Am i right?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your database schema, if you just want your expected result, please try following sql;)

```
select 
    case source_id when 1 then 'online' when 2 then 'visit' when 3 then 'phone' end as `Type`,
    sum(if(month(date_created) = 5, total_price, 0)) as `May`,
    sum(if(month(date_created) = 6, total_price, 0)) as `June`
from `orders`
where date_created between (curdate() - interval 1 month) and curdate()
group by source_id
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba39e/2).